# CSS - can i have an absolutely positioned scrollable element?

Tags: css, scrollbar, positioning, absolute

I know how to make an element scrollable (inner element absolute and parent relative), but what if I want the whole scrollable element to be positioned as absolute? (to move it around a parent div and overlap something underneath). Am i correct to assume it's not possible? Is there a way to do it via javascript?
I already tried to wrap the relative parent into an absolutely positioned grandparent but obviously it doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

Ok I actually solved it by moving the scrollable element into a component (I'm working in React), importing it into the main component, and then I set the position of the component to absolute. However, I'm still interested in knowing if other people have other solutions

Answer (score 0):

Can you just add an overflow on the absolute positioned item?

Something like this?

https://codepen.io/Daggett/pen/abqZgLa

CSS

```
section {
  width: 100v;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
  postion: relative
}

article {
  width: 20rem;
  height: 20rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: scroll;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2rem;
  left: 2rem;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50rem;
  background-color: green
}
```

HTML

```
<section>
  <article>
    <div></div>
  </article>
</section>
```